# GraphQL Subscription Schema implement in APIM

Tags: graphql, azure-api-management

Is the subscription schema fully supported by the Azure APIM?

using postman to connect to my gateway to the following playground http://snowtooth.moonhighway.com/

using the query

```
subscription {
  trailStatusChange {
    name
    status
  }
}
```

I get the following response

```
{
    "data": {
        "trailStatusChange": null
    }
}
```